# flex evaluating string for datagrid headerText

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating headerText for a datagrid (dgTop250).  How do I get the variable headerStr to evaluate correctly in the last line of the function?  With the code below I get the entire string as the column header in the datagrid, not the evaluated expression that I need.  Variable colName is evaluating correctly.  I tried creating an Object of headerStr and using Object.valueOf() in the last line, but got the same result as before.

```
public function get250(event:ResultEvent):void {
(var i:int = 0; i <= dgTop250.columnCount; i++) {
 var colName:String=dgTop250.columns[i].dataField;
 var headerStr:String="top250.lastResult.IMS001HQ2.SGM.getItemAt(i)."+colName+".label";
 (dgTop250.columns[i] as DataGridColumn).headerText = headerStr;
}
}
```

As an example, this is what I'm getting as the header:

> top250.lastResult.IMS001HQ2.SGM.getItemAt(i).STOCK.label

This is what I need:

> Stock Number

"Stock Number" is the label for STOCK.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

Change

```
var headerStr:String="top250.lastResult.IMS001HQ2.SGM.getItemAt(i)."+colName+".label";
```

to

```
 var headerStr:String=top250.lastResult.IMS001HQ2.SGM.getItemAt(i)[colName].label;
```

Correct answer provided by Don Mitchinson.